# Force Gradle to run task even if it is UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle

I came across a situation, when everything is UP-TO-DATE for Gradle, although I'd still like it to run the task for me. Obviously it does not:

```
gradle test
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.833 secs
```

I can force it to run **test** by running **clean test**, although this may be considered an overhead in some cases. Is there a way to force task execution no matter if Gradle believes it's UP-TO-DATE or not?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you want to rerun all tasks, you can use [command line parameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) `--rerun-tasks`. However this is basically the same as doing a clean as it reruns all the tasks.

If you want to run a single task every time, then you can specify that it is never up-to-date:

```
mytask {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

If you want to rerun a single task once and leave all the other tasks, you have to implement a bit of logic:

```
mytask {

    outputs.upToDateWhen { 
        if (project.hasProperty('rerun')) {
            println "rerun!"
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can force the task to be re-run by using:

`gradle mytask -Prerun`

Note that this will also re-run all the tasks that depend on `mytask`.

Comment: Note that if your task does not have any defined file inputs, Gradle may skip the task even when doing this!

Comment: I got an error, No signature of method: build_aoy2on2oal42mml5q3j55j0wu.test() is applicable

Answer (score 21):

In Gradle v7.6, [the new `--rerun` flag](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html#general-improvements) can tell an *individual* task to ignore up-to-date checks:

```
./gradlew theTask --rerun
```